# Concatenate all values of a pandas column into a string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a single pandas dataframe like this:

| EMP ID |
| --- |
| 1111 |
| 2222 |
| 3333 |
| 4444 |

I want to concatenate the values into a single string and store it in a variable like this:

emp_ids = "1111,2222,3333,4444"

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

use `','.join`:

```
emp_ids = ','.join(df['EMP ID'])
```

If the original type is not string (*e.g.*, int):

```
emp_ids = ','.join(df['EMP ID'].astype(str))
```